# Enable paging for a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

The grid changes the datasource depending on the command called:

Command one:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand="SELECT ItemDesc, TypeDesc, Total FROM vwTotal WHERE Admin = 0 ORDER BY Total DESC";
GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Command two:

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand="SELECT ItemDesc, TypeDesc, Total FROM vwTotal WHERE Admin = 1 ORDER BY Total DESC";
GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: the 2 most important parts here to know how to create a grid with pagination are the view and viewmodel. Not how you retrieve data from the DB or what data you're retrieving. So, share that part with us or look for examples from VM and V that do exactly that (I know there are plenity of them out there...).